# Positioning of an element using CSS in ASP.NET

Tags: css

I am learning about CSS and want to apply it in ASP.NET. I am struggling with the general positioning of the elements.

For example applying the following does not make much of a difference to the positioning of the element `.menu` for example.

```
.menu {
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    top: 355;
    left: 0;
}
```

In other words the menu element stays more or less in the top left hand corner no matter what I do.
What is the best why to manipulate the position of the various elements on an ASP.NET form?

This is the markup for `.menu`.

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Add Books</li>
        <li>Review Books</li>
        <li>Register</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, did you tried to remove css lines: top:355 and left:0 ?
Can you make an example on www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: what's your markup for the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re missing a unit of measurement for the `top` and `left` property values (though `left`’s being '`0`' it needn't one, because 0 is the same in any measurement).

Try with `top: 355px; left: 0;`.

In general you should also consider using [the `margin` property](http://w3.org/tr/css21/box.html#propdef-margin) before `position`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of given `top` and `left` you can define`margin`. In that case there is no need to set the position to absolute.

[Check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/5a7et/)

`margin:50px 0 0 30px;` means

top margin is 50px,

right margin is 0px,

bottom margin is 0px,

left margin is 30px